# Lets Encrypt + Cert Bot: Setting up known Certificate Authority

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, docker, letsencrypt

I have a setup in docker where I have `LetsEncrypt ACME Boulder + CertBot + DNSMASQ` as a DNS Server. Additionally I have a client and a service where  the service is served over https only.

I had first self signed a certificate and installed the same in both client and server. On making https calls, the system failed with the message that self signed certificates not allowed.

If i used `curl --insecure` flag, it works.

Next I setup a `Lets Encrypt Boulder + CertBot + DNSMASQ` to get a signed certificate from the same. When the certificates were used, the original error went away and a new error shows up:

> TLS handshake error from : remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority

From what I understand, I need to add the CA Certificates or somehow introduce the same as a trusted CA.

My questions:

- From where can I get the CA certificate of CertBot/Boulder to install the same in the client as well as server.
- Where all do I need to place the certificate, considering that I have `Scratch` or `Alpine` based Docker Images. This means the `update-ca-certificates` may or may not be available thus I cannot rely on the same. But am willing to know if it can solve my issue...
- Is there anything that I could be doing wrong..??